# AppCompatActivity не на весь экран в Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-support-library, android-appcompat

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моё `AppCompatActivity` запускается не на весь экран, даже со встренными appcompat-стилями. Я тестировал на пустом `activity` и когда оно наследуются от `AppCompatActivity` так же запускается в маленькой области, но когда наследуется  от `Activity` всё работает как надо.
Как мне исправить это?

С разрешением эмулятора, судя по всему, это никак не связано - сама ОС и другие приложения работают на весь экран, диалоги и обычные активности тоже отображаются нормально. Физического девайса для проверки, к сожалению нет.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: запускаете на эмуляторе? пробовали на реальном устройстве запускать?

Comment: @miha_dev, согласен, возможно такое разрешение экрана эмулятора стоит.